# Contractive mappings and fixed points

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

Hy friends,

In a metric space, we now that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ is not sufficient for the existence of a fixed point for $f$.

However, the results of Rakotch (A Note on Contractive Mappings, 1962) shows that if there is a function $\alpha(d(x,y))$ such that

1. $\alpha(x,y)=\alpha(d(x,y))$
2. $0 \leq \alpha(\rho) <1, \forall \rho>0$
3. $\alpha(\rho)$ is monotonically decreasing funtion of $\rho$,

we garantee the existence of a fixed point of a function $f$ if
$$d(f(x),f(y))<\alpha(x,y)d(x,y). \ \ \ \ (I)$$

**My question:** the function $f(x)=\ln(1+e^x)$ has no fixed point even if it is a weak contraction (note that $f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}<1$).

How to prove directly that there is no $\alpha$ satisfying (I) for this function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand. Is $\alpha$ a function of one input $\rho$ or two points $x,y$?

Comment: $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ and compactness **ARE**  sufficient for the existence of a fixed point for $f$.

Comment: if you did not mean to say **compactness** you should edit that out

Comment: @davidlowryduda $\alpha$ depends on $d(x,y)$. For each $x,y$ in the metric space we determine $d(x,y)$ and calculate $\alpha(d(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy. I had already edited! When I wrote, I thought about compactness of $f$, but I didnt write what I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$d(f(x),f(x+1))\leq\alpha(1)$$
but since
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+e^x)}x=1,$$
$d(f(x),f(x+1))>1-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$. This implies $\alpha(1)=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @Ariana, but I didn't get the relation between the limit and $d(f(x),f(x+1))$.

Comment: @CletoPereira It is equivalent to saying $\log\left(1+e^{x+1}\right)-\log(1+e^x)\approx x$ for big $x$

Comment: I got it! We have $d(f(x),f(x+1)) \equiv d(x, x+1)=1$ for big $x$. Thanks!